# How to group data specific field wise?

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I am getting data from database for specific category.
Suppose I select or pass data to query that category is Laptop then it give me data of all attribute and it's value.
Like :

[image]

My Code to getting and display data on JSP page is :

```
<%
            List<String> attribNameList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribName");
            List<String> attribValueList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribValue");
            List<String> attribDataList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribData");
            String aname,aval,adata;

            for(int i = 0 ; i<attribValueList.size() ; i++)
            {
                aname = attribNameList.get(i);
                aval = attribValueList.get(i);
                adata = attribDataList.get(i);

        %>
            <a><%=i%><%= aname %></a> &nbsp;
            <a><%= aval %></a> &nbsp;
            <%
                if(adata == null)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    %>
                        <a><%= adata %></a>
                    <%
                }
            %>

            <br>
        <%
            }
        %>
```

Here `aname` display attribute name i.e. `RAM, Processor, etc.`

`aval` display value i.e. `4, 2.8, etc.`

and `adata` display last data i.e. `GB, GHz, MP, etc.`

Now I want to display data as category wise like all memory attribute will display first.
Like :

```
RAM 4 GB
HDD 1 TB
Cache 3 MB, etc.
```

How can I display data in such format ?
I have tried using `if condition` where `adata` variable checked with

```
if(adata.equals("GB")||adata.equals("TB")||adata.equals("MB"))
{
    //memory category data display
}
else
{
    //Other data
}
```

but it isn't working.

Any Suggestion Please...

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a custom object to store your entries:

```
class MyDataRow implements Comparable<MyDataRow> {
    private String aname;
    private String aval;
    private String adata;

    // getters, setters, constructors etc

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyDataRow other) {
      final int BEFORE = -1;
      final int EQUAL = 0;
      final int AFTER = 1;

      if(other == null) return AFTER;
      if(other.getAdata().equals(this.adata)) return EQUALS;

      if(this.adata.equals("GB")||this.adata.equals("TB")||this.adata.equals("MB"))
      {
          if(other.getAdata().equals("GB") || xxxxxxx) return EQUAL;
          return BEFORE;
      }

      if(next category in the list... etc etc)
    }
}
```

Then the result of your database query populates a List. In MyDataRow, you override the 'compareTo' method with the ordering logic that you want. Before you enter the loop that prints out your list to the page, call Collections.sort(myDataRowList) :

```
List<MyDataRow> myDataRowList = new ArrayList<MyDataRow>();
for(int i = 0 ; i<attribValueList.size() ; i++)
{
       aname = attribNameList.get(i);
       aval = attribValueList.get(i);
       adata = attribDataList.get(i);
       myDataRowList.add(new MyDataRow(aname, aval, adata);
}

Collections.sort(myDataRowList); // now your myDataRowList is sorted in the order you want

for(MyDataRow myDataRow : myDataRowList) {

    // print rows to screen

}
```

Comment: Sir if possible then will you give me a small example ? Because what you want to tell me i just understand some portion.

Comment: I have added a bit of example code - I am away from my dev environment right now so I have not tried to compile it, and you will need to fill in the extra information, but hopefully this gives you the idea?

Comment: Means Sir I have to add this code in Java file ? Shall I have to remove code from JSP page ? And how to receive all code to jsp page ?

Comment: I would recommend putting the MyDataRow class in a separate file, like MyDataRow.java. Then add the sorting logic in your jsp file where you print out the data

Comment: Okay let me try it. ANd inform you if I ll face any problem. BTW thanks for the help.